# Python Pandas: Vlookup across multiple dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has a specific list of email addresses like:

```
Email
123@abc.com
234@abc.com
```

My master list of email contact info is split up across 5 pandas dataframes (imported from excel). I need to vlookup across these 5 dataframes to pull the first_name & last_names of the contacts in my initial dataframe. Is there a quick way of doing this?

EDIT: The other dataframes would have email addresses as the primary identifier, with separate columns for first_name & last_name like:

```
Email|first_name|last_name
123@abc.com|James|Bond
234@abc.com|Jason|Bourne
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. Could you post a few example lines from those other DataFrames (as text, not images) and provide some expected output?

Comment: I edited the initial question to add examples from the other dataframes. All the other dataframes are identical to each other - the main issue that they were too big to be stored in a single excel file, so they were split up. I need to vlookup across all of them to get their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've imported the Excel file(s) using `df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file)`, you can use `pd.merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Email': ['123@abc.com', '234@abc.com']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Email': ['123@abc.com', '234@abc.com'], 
                    'first_name': ['James', 'Jason'], 
                    'last_name': ['Bond', 'Bourne']})

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Email')
         Email first_name last_name
0  123@abc.com      James      Bond
1  234@abc.com      Jason    Bourne
```

Comment: That worked - I used concat to join the dataframes together and then merge worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Abhay, that's great to hear!